# i have problem with install inventory in magento version 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3.4

my problem with install Inventory i have module this module installing with inventory modules i downloaded all the add-ons Inventory and i put it in app/code/magento Like the instructions provided But when giving command

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

i get this error

Service method specified in the definition of topic "async.V1.inventory.bulk-product-source-assign.POST" is not available. Given "Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Api\BulkSourceAssignInterface::execute"

But when giving command

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

i get this error

-bash-4.2$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [==>-----------------]  14% < 1 sec 78.5 MiB
Fatal error: Interface 'Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\GetProductTypesBySkusInterface' not found in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Magento/InventoryCatalog/Model/ResourceModel/GetProductTypesBySkus.php on line 17

i use version 2.3.4 of magento and i want to install inventory with The right install without a problem Because there is an important add-on for me and my store, I installed it, but it requires installation Inventory

Record report Error

[image]

Error of debug.log

[image]

and this error of system.log

[image]

and this error from exception.log

```
[2023-11-01 08:45:29] main.CRITICAL: Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system. {"report_id":"9710be8a4fb157c494c51d9812b399847ce4779107ef35b50a0e877fdf6291af","exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Unable to retrieve deployment version of static files from the file system. at /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View/Deployment/Version.php:88)"} []
```

When all components are deleted Inventory Modules my store back work no problem but my problem must me install Inventorey to install some modules i have

Comment: Hi Nino, please let me know if I understood it correctly, you need to install an add-on that requires inventory modules of Magento. When you install the inventory module you start getting mentioned errors however when you remove those modules store works just fine. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes @Rishabh Dwivedi i have problem to install Inventory and if i'm deleted the Inventory my store back again work easy with all commands but if i put Inventory again stop work with commands setup:di:compile setup:upgrade but i have commands work like static-content:deploy indexer:reindex and i want install Inventory to make my module work

Comment: From where did you get your inventory modules, this is the correct version of Inventory modules to install with Magento 2.3.4 https://github.com/magento/inventory/releases/tag/1.1.6. Also, did you try installing those modules using Composer? You can try installing it using "composer install magento/inventory-composer-metapackage" as well. This will install the appropriate version compatible with your magento version.

Comment: Rishabh i'm downloading Inventory on Link you send and all commands working fine but last command setup:di:compile i get this error  Class Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\SourceItemsProcessor does not exist

Comment: We can debug that, however, could you please remove all those modules first and try with composer once it may or may not solve the problem but placing the core module in the app/code folder is not recommended unless you are a contributor. Also, please check if all the inventory modules are there and enabled. Let me know, what you find.

Comment: this sloved Rishabh i'm created file with this name SourceItemsProcessor.php

Comment: I am glad but this shouldn't be happening in the first place and not the right way to fix it. Anyway, if you are okay with it then it's fine to me :)

Comment: Yes Mr Rishabh i'm fix it with AI and work fine